# Restructure data loaded from dropbox file in python

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to download data from a CSV file stored in a dropbox folder. So far I do like this:

```
import dropbox

#Get access to my dropbox folder
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('SOME_ACCESS_TOKEN')
dbx.users_get_current_account()

#Download file    
metadata, res = dbx.files_download('/Test.csv')

#Get the file content
data=res.content
print(data)
```

data is of the this form: b'1,2,3,4,5\r\nA,B,C,D,E\r\n1,2,3,4,5\r\nA,B,C,D,E\r\n1,2,3,4,5\r\nA,B,C,D,E\r\n'

Is there an easy way to restructure this into a list of lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the above mentioned problem is:

```
import dropbox

#Connect to dropbox folder
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('SOME_ACCESS_TOKEN')
dbx.users_get_current_account()

#Get metadata
metadata, res = dbx.files_download('/Test.txt')

#Get and decode data
data=res.content.decode('utf-8')

#Restructure data
lines = data.split('\r\n')
lines.pop()

print(lines)
```